# What to do so that issue.net shows readable banner characters to chinese russian french ssh users

Tags: ssh, internationalization, sshd, banner

I set up my ssh server and added custom issue.net config. when loggin, it shows \320\237\320\264\321.... for characters other than ascii-7

Is it a client side issue or do I manage this at server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is not possible for the banner to have non-ASCII characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109038/non-printable-ascii-characters-in-sshd-banner#109045). ssh filters non-ascii characters and prints them as octal text. This is done for security reasons, to prevent attacks on the client by sending terminal control characters.

Comment: Thank you man, I love this definitive and well explained answer.