# Characters not displayed correctly on Konsole from the SSH banner

Tags: 16.04, ssh, fonts, encoding, konsole

I have configured a ssh banner on my remote server:

```
███████╗ █████╗ ███╗   ██╗ █████╗ ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗ █████╗ ███╗   ██╗██████╗ 
╚══███╔╝██╔══██╗████╗  ██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║ ██╔╝██╔══██╗████╗  ██║██╔══██╗
  ███╔╝ ███████║██╔██╗ ██║███████║██████╔╝█████╔╝ ███████║██╔██╗ ██║██║  ██║
 ███╔╝  ██╔══██║██║╚██╗██║██╔══██║██╔══██╗██╔═██╗ ██╔══██║██║╚██╗██║██║  ██║
███████╗██║  ██║██║ ╚████║██║  ██║██║  ██║██║  ██╗██║  ██║██║ ╚████║██████╔╝
╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚═════╝
```

that is correctly displayed when I login via `ssh` using my OSX machine. But instead when I connect with my Ubuntu machine using **Konsole** I get:

```
\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227   \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227   \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 
\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\235\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\235\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227
  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\235 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\235\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\235 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221
 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\235  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\225\232\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227 \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\225\232\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221
\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221 \342\225\232\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\227\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221  \342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221 \342\225\232\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\221\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\226\210\342\225\224\342\225\235
\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235  \342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235  \342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235  \342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235  \342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235  \342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235  \342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\235  \342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\235\342\225\232\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\220\342\225\235
```

I already read around about problems of characters not displaying in terminal, but for what I can understand all the suggested configuration settings are properly shown:

`locale`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`echo $TERM`

`xterm-256color`

`uname -a`

`Linux *** 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Konsole** is correctly configured with `UTF-8` encoding and the font I'm using is `Meslo LG M DZ for Poweline`

The same configuration on iTerm2 on osx shows correctly the characters as I said.

Comment: It could be related to openssh? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109038/non-ascii-printable-characters-in-sshd-banner

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502987/what-to-do-so-that-issue-net-shows-readable-banner-characters-to-chinese-russian) they suggest that it may not be possible, but the strange thing is that with my Mac I see correctly the ASCII art writing.

Comment: Your systems are using different versions os OpenSSH and different vendor patches so from here the difference.